# Windows XP doesn't recognize Ubuntu 10.04 DVD

Tags: installation, 10.04, dvd

my problem is next: I insert Ubuntu 10.04 (I want 10.04 not any other versions, cause my computer cannot run them) DVD, and turn on my computer. I'm waiting for a while in hope that it'll start live preview and give me the chance to install it, but it just skips on the windows xp start up. I checked BIOS setting they are seted up like they should be, DVD works 100% cause I installed ubuntu 10.04 from the same DVD on machine that is runned by windows 8. So, what can be problem and how can I solve it? I really need Ubuntu for my studying! 
I hope somebody will help me.
Regards All.

Comment: have you checked the priorities of booting devices?

CD/DVD must be at higher priority than hard disk

Answer (score 1):

try following steps:

Solution A:

1. Boot to Windows and check if it can read the DVD without any problems
2. If not, try using different DVD media (DVD+R(W) / DVD-R(W))
3. Make your DVD drive be the first in boot order (check BIOS option)

Solution B:

1. Use bootable USB (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
2. Note: Don't forget changing the BIOS options first

Solution C:

There is a very nice article that describes all possible ways how the Ubuntu could be installed: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Installation_without_a_CD

I hope that you'll be successful :-).

Comment: I wrote it already: ,,I checked BIOS settings they are setted up like they should be..." I don't have USB memory, and windows can read any type of DVD format.

Comment: Does this help?
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000217.htm

Answer (score 0):

did you change the boot media priority in your bios?
Usually a pc with preinstalle windows comes with the hdd windows is installed on as standard bootmedia setting.

Enter your bios-menu and check this issue.

Comment: I wrote it already: ,,I checked BIOS settings they are setted up like they should be..."

Comment: alternatively you can deacrtivate your windows partition in bios, so your pc has no other option than booting from cd.
This woprked for me once I had the same problem.

Comment: will the Win XP machine read any other DVDs?